# mysql getting all possible months from datetime field

Tags: mysql, datetime, archive

so i have a table with hundreds records. And a have a filed name "created" type with a datetime format. Now I want to make and archive with the months. For example January, February.... etc. I need to create query to find all possible months. For example if my records start from 2011/05/01 to now I will need to fetch the months that means months 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12. 
Is there a way to that ???

Comment: Do you want to select records for a specific month and year?

Comment: 100s of records... why archive... even with 100,000s why archive... MySQL can blow through that without breaking a sweat if you are concerned about performance.  If you ever want to get data back from the archives, you'll have to "JOIN" any query to the archives data too which would cause its own performance hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the `DATE_FORMAT` function and other date and time functions.

More details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

For example, if you want all your records for December 2011:

`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE YEAR(created) = 2011 AND MONTH(created) = 12`

Comment: genius :) helped me a lot! the exact query i will use is "SELECT Distinct MONTH(date) FROM events"

Comment: However, you might want to accept Karlson's answer, as it is more complete.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking at the list of all Months present in the `created` field (as I understand your query) then do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(MONTH(created)) FROM posts;
```

The resulting set would be the list of unique months in the field.  If this will complain then try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(MONTH(DATE(created))) FROM posts;
```

You can then substitute `MONTH` for `MONTHNAME` and get names instead.  I did not add the `WHERE` clause to these queries but you can limit the dataset you are looking at as you see fit.

For more information take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/functions.html this has a list of quite a few functions that MySQL natively provides.